# nested key property requirements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand when using arrays of Components the key property is assumed to be the index of the array, and should be explicitly set. Are the children of those children recommended to be explicitly set?

```
{arr.map(item, i) => {
  <Parent
    key={item.ID}
  >
    <Child
      key={`child${item.ID`}   //required to ensure correct reconciliation?
    />
  </Parent>
}
```

Comment: Not required or needed, unless you plan on making changes to the children (adding new ones, removing in the future). Keys are mainly for performance. If one parent changes, React knows "hey, this key changed, update that parent with this key". Otherwise, it'd say "a parent changed, but I don't know which one, we'll re-render all of them." And since it's a tree, the full subtree is re-rendered too, which is why you wouldn't need to provide a key for the child if it will remain the same (and why composition over inheritance (less nesting) is better for performance).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity ([source](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys))

The general purpose of a `key` is to optimize React's rendering performance. If you have a list of items, giving a key tells React how to remember this item for subsequent renders. If you use an array index, that can defeat the purpose of the `key` (if the order of those elements change). [Its better to use a unique ID or something more specific to the entity being rendered](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys).

With that context, The parent element is what needs the key, so React can do its optimizations. The children of that "dynamic" element are attached to that parent / its key so there's no need to apply a `key` on the children`. Just the parents that are rendered in a loop :)

Comment: It's not just purely optimization. The `key` is what uniquely identifies the component to React so that it can track its internal state. If you switch keys around on components you will see that their `state` gets switched as well.

Comment: Sure, but part of tracking its internal state is for optimizations :)

Answer (score 2):

only the outermost items you iterate you need to set a key on. As far as I see there's a single child component per Parent, so no need to worry abot key in this case

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to explicitly set keys on the children.

The follow is a good article on using keys: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

It explicitly recommends not using indexes as keys for an array:

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key. If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys.

Answer (score 1):

No, you only need it for the outer component (Parent). [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: Thanks, namely [Keys Must Only Be Unique Among Siblings](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings)